# How to set text in onSensorChange metod +accelerometer

Tags: android, textview, sensors

Thanks in advance.

I m working in game application using accelerometer. but i've facing a problem,
when i update textview in "onSensorChange" method of accelerometer.application not perform 
good.

My code like this.

```
int nCounter = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mTV_CountTextView = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.TextView);
}
```

....
......

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
            // Set sensor values as acceleration
            yAcceleration = sensorEvent.values[1];
            xAcceleration = sensorEvent.values[2];

                            nCounter++; 
                             mTV_CountTextView.settext(""+nCounter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one..

```
mTV_CountTextView.settext(""+String.valueOf(nCounter));
```

may be your are using Integer for settext so you are getting error..

Answer (score 0):

1. setText() instead of settext ?
2. You're polling the Orientation sensor's values to look at the device acceleration o_O ?