# Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String) in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, settext

I am using the Pedometer to count the steps since the last reboot of a device.

I have created a textView which I want to set the text of to be the number of steps when the sensor is being used. (My TextView is called count)

My code for doing this is:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (activityRunning) {
        count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
    }
```

I am getting an error here `Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String)`

I can post the rest of the class if it would help to fix the problem

Thanks

This is the rest of the class:

```
public class Tab3 extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private TextView textView;
boolean activityRunning;
private Button buttonReturn;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);

    TextView count = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.count);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    activityRunning = true;
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if (countSensor != null) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Count sensor not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    activityRunning = false;
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (activityRunning) {
        count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
}
```

This is the XML file associated with this class:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.application.placepicker.TabbedActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Step counter"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:text="Steps walked so far today:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="---"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="36dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it just simply means that your count object doesn't have setText method. make sure that you instantiated the textview on your oncreate or even from there in your onsensorchanged method

Comment: Yep, a bit more context would help, if you can post the rest of the code.

Comment: Show us the count object

Comment: I suspect you typed as TextureView instead? :)

Comment: I have uploaded the rest of the class now guys, thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you look at `count` it´s only declared inside `onCreate` you need to move it outside

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/10911539

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
private TextView textView;
```

to

```
private TextView count;
```

And change

```
TextView count = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.count);
```

to

```
count = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.count);
```

Comment: I have done this and the error has gone. I just hadn't initialised it properly. When I run the app now though it crashes and the Android Monitor reads: 
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at com.example.application.placepicker.Tab3.onSensorChanged(Tab3.java:77)"

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Bring "count" out of "onCreateView", so it will be accessiable in "onSensorChanged"

```
public class Tab3 extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {
 private SensorManager sensorManager;
 private TextView textView;
 boolean activityRunning;
 private Button buttonReturn;

private TextView count ;//<-- add this

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);

    //define count global 
    count = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.count);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    activityRunning = true;
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if (countSensor != null) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Count sensor not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    activityRunning = false;
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (activityRunning) {
        count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
}
```

Comment: I have done this exactly as you have done above and I am still getting the same error - `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at com.example.application.placepicker.Tab3.onSensorChanged(Tab3.java:79)`
In my else statement, I am using `Toast.makeText` and then calling `getActivity()` is this correct?

Comment: where did you create count? is it in the "R.layout.tab3".  change count = (TextView)  **rootView**.findViewById(R.id.count); if it doesn't work please share R.layout.tab3

Comment: Yes I created count in the tab3.xml file. I will update the question now to include the XML file.

Comment: you are using inflate so replace 'count = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.count);' WITH 'count = (TextView) **rootView**.findViewById(R.id.count) '

Answer (score 0):

How did you define your "count"?

If we suppose that you has defined the TextView correctly, you will get error in null object, 
so it is better to change your code to below:

```
   count.setText(""+event.values[0]);
```

Comment: I have done this and the error has gone. I just hadn't initialised it properly. When I run the app now though it crashes and the Android Monitor reads: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.example.application.placepicker.Tab3.onSensorChanged(Tab‌​3.java:77)" Any idea what is causing this?